# Incorrect width on iPad

Tags: css, ipad, html

After starting work for a new company, I've been charged with building a new site for them. This is what I've got so far:

http://ghostevolution.com/ghostds/

The problem is that it isn't working correctly on the iPad - the header background colour doesn't stretch across the full width of the screen like it is meant to - this is also true of the mid-section light-grey background colour on pages such as http://ghostevolution.com/ghostds/?page_id=160

Does anyone know why this is? Thank you.

Comment: Please post relevant code and/or a screen shot in here. Otherwise, this question loses all value to future generations once the problem has been solved. Thanks!

Comment: Agree with Pekka. Also, what are you using to determine if the user is on an iPad? I looked for `@media` queries but couldn't find any in your css. I would then assume PHP... we need to know the code you have for display on the iPad before we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to issue that is often forgotten (in desktop browsers as well). I'm pretty sure..

You see, with any desktop browser. Change the width of the window less than your wrapper width and scroll to the right. That would show the page as cut off.

This can be fixed quite easily.
<sub>*removed csspivot site since its no longer running*</sub>

The basic idea is to add the same background that gets cut off into element that has fixed width since browser can't do anything to that.

Add CSS:

```
#auxiliary .wrap {
background-color: #bbb; /* Same as the #auxiliary bg color*/
}

#branding .wrap {
border-top: 6px #92C201 solid; /* Same as #branding border and bg and height*/
background-color: #333;
height: 60px;
margin-top: -6px; /* I wouldnt necessarily use this to get it to top but works as well. */
}
```

Comment: What? This has nothing to do with the OP's question, and is not a fix for their problem.

Comment: No.. The issue has to do with the .wrap elements themselves, the widths aren't set to be a fluid 100% and they aren't properly structured to contain inline and floating elements.

Answer (score 0):

The half-assed proper way to do this is to wrap your contents in a container that spans 100% of the screen width. For example:

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0; /* add some top + bottom padding */
    background-color: #252525;
}
.aligner {
    display: block;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;    
}
.container {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="aligner">
        <div class="container">
            // stuff
        </div><!-- /container -->
    </div><!-- /aligner -->
</div><!-- /wrapper -->
```

It's not the prettiest, but it allows you to throw 100% width background-colors on any section, and works in < IE8. You can do whatever you need to within `div.container` (float, position, etc) and it will expand the .wrapper element (thus expanding your background color).

Each `div.wrapper` should be treated as a "section" - 'header', 'feature', 'content', 'footer', etc...

---

Another alternative is to start using `@media` queries, which would allow you to essentially plug in code for specific screen widths (880/1024px for iPad, portrait/landscape).

```
@media screen and (max-width: 880px) {
    .my_element {
        /* attributes */
    }
}
```