# iPhone Safari view background repeat-x not working

Tags: css

It seems like repeat-x for background property is not working on iphone safari browser.

Is there an alternative solution to this issue?

Comment: Show a http://jsfiddle.net please.

Comment: this is for getpickedup.wmetools.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Background-repeat-x/y doesn't work in Firefox/Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52382864/background-repeat-x-y-doesnt-work-in-firefox-safari)

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `repeat-x` or `repeat-y` but just `repeat`.
Works, tested.

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking this might be the problem with your page...

[Incorrect width on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7468246/incorrect-width-on-ipad/7468353#7468353) Note that even though the guy never accepted.. My way of doing it at least solved that problem..

On ipad like half of his page bg and header and footer went missing. This is really quick fix ( if you have the same problem ), basically you just set the same background ( the one that gets cut off ) *again* in inner elements that have a static width. Static width is the key word here, because window width doesn't cut those off.

Also as stated in that answer, in desktop browsers if window width is smaller than page width and you scroll to the right it will cut the bg. That is very common thing to see actually.. your page does the same.

Im fairly certain this will solve your ipad issue.