# Background-repeat-x/y doesn't work in Firefox/Safari

Tags: css, firefox

I have code below demonstrates that `background-repeat-x/y` for some reason doesn't work on FireFox. It just strikes out those styles (but not like they're incorrect + they aren't overridden somewhere).
When I try to combine these styles in one (`background`) it also strikes it out. Can get why this happens. Haven't found anything similar.

```css
.myDiv {
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url(https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/37912316/38108463-2d5980dc-3395-11e8-948a-d7fd97647f86.png);
  background-repeat-x: no-repeat;
  background-repeat-y: repeat;
  
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="myDiv">
        <p>Some text</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: use `background-repeat:repeat-y` this syntax is not standard, seems to work only with chrome

Comment: @TemaniAfif you're right. That worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: from where you get this syntax? I found nothing about it in the spec (even in the futur draft) so I am a bit suprised it works on Chrome, it should fail everywhere

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat

Comment: @TemaniAfif it was on W3Schools before. But find it now.

Comment: @Temani Afif: https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2017Jan/0064.html https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2017Feb/0052.html

Comment: @BoltClock I don't know how you are able to find all those stuffs :p thanks ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `background-repeat: repeat-y;` instead.

```
background-repeat-x: no-repeat;
background-repeat-y: repeat;
```

Can't be found in documentation.